# dynamic linq query - OrderBy with properties that are null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using The Ordering-By-String extensions from here:
http://blog.cincura.net/229310-sorting-in-iqueryable-using-string-as-column-name/

In my datasource, some objects may be null, and therefore won't have a property of EHR (see screenshot).

How can I capture this case? I still want the nulls to be included in the ordered list, but just at the bottom or top.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: Some more clarification..**

So my KendoUI grid is sending back a request to the server to order by a particular column. The column selected to orderby is "Month10.EHR". Month10 is a SubObject and EHR is the property. Some SubObjects don't exist and therefore don't have a property, and the subobject will be null. When performing the ordering, it notices that Month10 doesn't exist for one record, and therefore can't include it in the orderby.

I hope this makes sense.

Mike

[image: Error]

Comment: The code calling the extension would be more useful than the code inside the ordering helper, to see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where` to remove the elements which have a null order key, then use `Concat` to add them back again.

E.g.

```
IEnumerable List<Person> myList;
// ...
var orderedList = myList
    .Where(p => p.Age != null)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Age)
    .Concat(myList.Where(p => p.Age == null));
```

From reading your question again, it appears that you mean that the actual elements being sorted are null. What's the point of including them in the list at all in that case?

Comment: I think this is close to what I need, except I'm ordering using a string for propertyname with reflection, not a fixed type (i.e. age). Not quite sure how to get this working dynamically

Comment: Have you tried it with a set where Month10.EHR exists for ALL elements?

Answer (score 1):

Test for `null` in the OrderBy Function.

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> myList;
// ...
var orderedList = myList.OrderBy(obj =>
                    obj == null 
                    || obj.Month10 == null 
                  ? defaultValue : obj.Month10.EHR);
```

Comment: I've clarified my question further. I'm trying to orderby on subobject's properties, and the subobject may not exist. I'm using dynamic linq and reflection to pass the column name through, so this isn't quite what I'm trying to do

Comment: Month10.EHR is not the only column they could click, however. There are 12 columns. I.e. Month1.EHR, Month2.EHR etc. I guess I would have to check them all?